# Prove $(a+b)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}\right)\geq9$ with $a>0$ and $b > 0$. When does equality hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Prove that $(a+b)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{4}{b}\right)\geq9$ with $a>0$ and $b > 0$. When does equality hold?

**My attempt:**

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have:

$$\begin{align*}(a+b)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{4}{b}\right)&\geq{\left(\sqrt{a\cdot\dfrac{1}{a}}+\sqrt{b\cdot\dfrac{4}{b}}\right)}^2\\&={\left(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{4}\right)}^2\\&={\left(1+2\right)}^2\\&=(3)^2\\&=9\end{align*}$$

Is it correct?

I'm having trouble showing when equality holds. Could someone help me to understand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)(\frac1a + \frac4b) \ge 9 \iff  (a+ \frac{b}{2} + \frac{b}{2})(\frac1a + \frac2b + \frac2b) \ge 9$.  By AM $\ge$ HM.... BTW, what you have is correct, For equality in CS, you need the two "vector" proportional to each other....

Comment: Say equality holds when $b=ra$.  Then $r=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inequality your method is correct, but when equality occurs is ..
Well, one must note that Cauchy-Schwarz is AM-GM in disguise:
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) \ge (ac+bd)^2 \iff 
a^2d^2+b^2c^2 \ge 2abcd$$
And as in AM-GM, equality occurs if $ad=bc$, applying this to your case we get 
$$\sqrt{\frac{4a}{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} \iff 2a=b$$

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b\ne 0$, then $(a+b)\left(\frac1{a}+\frac{4}{b}\right)=9\iff(a+b)(b+4a)=9ab\iff(2a-b)^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

They called it the Titu's lemma in the inequality world or the Angel form of the CS inequality. The inequality follows from this lemma: $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{4}{b} = \dfrac{1^2}{a}+\dfrac{2^2}{b} \ge \dfrac{(1+2)^2}{a+b} = \dfrac{9}{a+b}$.